# Track if a component is on or off screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component A that renders once the application loads.

I am looking to render another component B the moment component A leaves

the screen. This happens when the user scrolls component A off screen.

And also when user scrolls component A back into the screen, component B should

disappear.

Looking for guidance on how I could track whether component A is on the screen or off screen in React.

Please advice.

Idea is below. Looking for a way to listen if component A is on screen or not and setShowB(false) or setShowB(true) accordingly.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const AComponent = () => {
  const [showB, setShowB] = useState(false); // I do want this to be a boolean
  const setVisibility = (showB) => showB ? 'visible' : 'hidden'

  return (
    <div>

      <div id='A' style={{ visibility: setVisibility(showB)}}>
        I am component A
      </div>

      <div id='B'>
        I am component B
      </div>

    </div>
  );
};

export default AComponent;
```

Note: Not looking to use any external libraries.

On page load only Component A shows.

[image]

===================================================================

when component A is scrolled off screen component B shows up.

[image]

Comment: Hello Mate !
 I am trying to look for a React solution for you.

As per the requirement,  You are saying only 1 Component should be displayed at a time. When a user scrolls a particular Component , that particular component should be removed of the DOM and another should be shown up at its place.

My question to scroll up to the height of the Component, we must have more content on the page so that we are able to scroll on the page.

Could you share the design of what you want to achieve, so that I can try to come up with a solution. :)

Thanks

Comment: I would like to connect with you friend for this particular scenario, because I am trying to create the exact scenario. If you wish we can do this together here.  I do not have all the context :)

Comment: The scenario is going to be somewhat like this:

https://codesandbox.io/s/help-friend-stackoverflow-x15jf

Comment: @Flappy: When you say  "when ComponentA is scrolled off the screen", We can only scroll a Component when its height is greater than the ViewPort or we have more content below it. So that we can scroll.

So, could you provide any design about what you wish to achieve.  Is there more stuff below the ComponentA as it first loads.

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather Updated question if it it helps clarify. Component B is a Sticky Component always stays on the bottom.

Comment: @Flappy: let me see. Thanks

Comment: @Flappy: I got it, It means there is some other content or elements below ComponentA and that's why we are able to scroll. And once it is scrolled upto bottom ComponentB is shows Up. Right?

I think I can give it a try. Would you like to connect to do it together via Zoom??? This way you can suggest me what you are looking for exactly and may learn new stuff

Comment: @Flappy: If you check the link: https://codesandbox.io/s/help-friend-stackoverflow-x15jf?file=/src/App.jsyou can see. I am initially rendering ComponentA. I have given it 100Vh. 

Again, This initially is not scrollable, because we can only scroll a page when the page has Elements or content greater than the viewport height.

I am asking you the same thing/ Hope you are getting my ponit.
I am saying is there more content besides ComponentA and ComponentB

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather That's correct. There are other components other than Component A which is why able to scroll. Sorry do not have zoom to begin with. Just looking for a general guidance on how I could go about doing this.

Comment: Dear Friend @Fllappy, I got the context now. No problem, let me try to come  up with a solution for this. InshaAllah.

Give me a moment My Friend

Comment: Give me a moment, Stay online. I might come up with questions as I am trying it.

Comment: Question: Are the heights of ComponentA and ComponentB always the same???

Comment: Hi Yes there are always of same height.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235072/discussion-between-imran-rafiq-rather-and-fllappy).

Comment: I have provided a quick solution. You can build on top of it as per your requirement. Some tweeks are definitely required. That would be a good exercise for you. The basic Logic is what I have provided for you.

Have a great time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this solution and build on top of this as per your requirement. You need to use **useEffect()** Hook to put all your scrolling code and manage state accordingly. useEffect() is used to manage all the sideEffects and for user scrolling **useEffect()** is the best place to write our Logic.

**CODESANDBOX:** https://codesandbox.io/s/help-friend-stackoverflow-x15jf?file=/src/App.js

**TOTAL COMPONENTS USED:**

**App.js**

```
import "./styles.css";
import ComponentA from "./components/ComponentA";
import ComponentB from "./components/ComponentB";
import OtherComponent from "./components/OtherComponent";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [isAOpen, setIsAOpen] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
      // let componentHeight = document.querySelector(".compA").clientHeight;
      let scrolled = window.scrollY;

      console.log(scrolled);

      if (scrolled >= 530) {
        setIsAOpen(false);
      } else if (scrolled <= 10) {
        setIsAOpen(true);
      }
    });

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", () => {
        // let componentHeight = document.querySelector(".compA").clientHeight;
        let scrolled = window.scrollY;

        console.log(scrolled);

        if (scrolled >= 530) {
          setIsAOpen(false);
        } else if (scrolled < 0) {
          setIsAOpen(true);
        }
      });
    };
  }, [isAOpen]);

  return (
    <main>
      {isAOpen ? <ComponentA /> : <ComponentB />}
      <OtherComponent />
    </main>
  );
}
```

**ComponentA.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const ComponentA = () => {
  return (
    <main className="compA">
      <h1>COMPONENT-AYE</h1>
    </main>
  );
};

export default ComponentA;
```

**ComponentB.js**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

const ComponentB = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("component-B showing up");
  });
  return (
    <main className="compB">
      <h1>COMPONENT-Bee</h1>
    </main>
  );
};

export default ComponentB;
```

**OtherComponent.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const OtherComponent = () => {
  return (
    <main className="compOther">
      <h1>OTHER COMPONENT AND DATA</h1>
    </main>
  );
};

export default OtherComponent;
```

**For simplicity I have kept all the styles in styles.css file**

**style.css**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.compA,
.compB {
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.compA {
  background: green;
}
.compB {
  background: rgb(238, 94, 58);
  margin-top: 500px;
}

.compOther {
  height: 130vh;
  background: rgb(58, 241, 241);
}
```

**Note:** you need to make some basic changes while scrolling back to top (perhaps remove the margin-top on ComponentB. That's an exercise for you. Cheers !!!)

Answer (score 1):

You could use IntersectionObserver API:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Here’s an example of it being used with React:

https://dev.to/producthackers/intersection-observer-using-react-49ko

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library for handling scrolling enter or leave events.
https://github.com/civiccc/react-waypoint

Answer (score 0):

You can use onMouseLeave or onMoustOut event listener to check it , In react can be implemented like below

```
import "./styles.css";
import {useState} from 'react'

export default function App() {
  const [showA,setShowA]=useState(true)
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {showA ?  <div style={{width:'100%',height:'100vh',backgroundColor:"red"}} onMouseLeave={()=>setShowA(!showA)}></div>:     <div style={{width:'100%',height:'100vh',backgroundColor:"blue"}} onMouseLeave={()=>setShowA(!showA)}></div>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can refer to codesanbox below

[image: Edit bold-frog-pbnbx]

Comment: Isn't on mouse leave about the mouse leaving the component? The question is on the component being scrolled up off screen.